paddleocr, how to training own dataset
I using PaddleOCR for project and get trained_model at https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/main/doc/doc_en/models_list_en.md. But nothing changed.
So I hope to train my own dataset.
There are images, boxes (x,y,width,height), and text in my dataset.
But I don't know the data structure for fine-tuning and what code to run.
Thank you and have a good day.

ocr = PaddleOCR(cls=True,
                use_angle_cls=False,
                lang="korean",use_gpu=True,
                rec_model_dir='/ocr/korean_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/'
)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(object_crops[l])
factor = 2.5
enhanced_image = enhancer.enhance(factor)
result = ocr.ocr(np.array(enhanced_image))
ed=time.time()
ocr_result = result[0]


